# Why does browser not render some CSS it's loaded?

Tags: html, css, nginx

My CSS file is being loaded by the browser. I can see it in the list of network resources in developer tools, and if I visit the CSS file directly, I can see the file. It appears to have the correct type (stylesheet).

But, despite everything being downloaded correctly, the browser doesn't render the content according to the rules in this CSS file.

I have no idea what's causing this.

My link from the head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/components.css">
```

It's being served by nginx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you double-check you have the right selectors? Maybe typos?
2. Did you double-check you're not overriding something? Maybe with inline styles?
3. Did you double-check the CSS properties you are using are supported by the browser on which you do the test?

Those are the 3 things that I can think of for now. You can try to be more specific for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Carried on looking. Although developer console reported the type as 'stylesheet', the mime-type was coming as text/plain. I've fixed my server configuration and now get the CSS rendered.

Thanks for the suggestions.